# Long/Int with 64bits in windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I know that in Unixes/Linuxes the `long` size is 64bit.

But when using the same under the windows (x64) the `long` is always 32bit.

Is there any workaround/library that enable the use of *larger integers* in C ?

Comment: In C++ we use `long long`, not 100% certain that applies to C. (I normally use `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` if I need something that toggles depending on the build)

Comment: Bear in mind that the size of types also depends on the compiler, so there may be a compiler that uses a 64 bit `long` type.

Comment: Yep, it is a compiler thing not an operating system thing...but the problem was solved a long long time ago...

Comment: Try `#include <stdint.h>`, then use `int64_t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under C99, you have two possibilities

- Use `long long`, since it is required to be at least 64-bit
- If available, use `int64_t`, or `int_least64_t`, from `stdint.h`

In the second approach, you may find it useful to combine with `inttypes.h`, which adds portable formatting and conversion functions, but note that while `stdint.h` is required in both hosted and freestanding implementations, `inttypes.h` is only required in hosted implementations.

Also, exactly which types are defined in `stdint.h` is implementation-defined in some cases, but if a type is defined, then both signed and unsigned versions must exist.